# Twice GTM code installed, does GA count hits twice?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

If a website has two GTM code installed, how does GA count traffic? Does it mean the traffic we see in GA report is duplicate?

They are different containers but same GA property.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both containers have the same GA account and both populate on the page (e.g. have the same rules), then yes, you'll have double the pageviews.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, why do you have 2 GTM codes?
When you set up a container and install the GTM on every page, you must also set up GA tracking as one of your tags on the Tag Manager container settings, when you set this up, you will have to choose which pages you wish to track, most likely, you need to select "All pages". With the live preview you can verify your tag is working and you can go to the GA real time traffic dashboard to make sure data is being recorded appropriately, of course, depending on your traffic, it might not be easy to tell if you are double-counting.

I guess I would say if you set up your Universal Analytics tag properly, you shouldn't have duplicate data...

Back to my question, maybe I can help you better if I know why exactly you have 2 GTM codes?

:)